# Exception Found - java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format in jmeter

Tags: exception, jmeter, gzip

i'm trying to run the recorded script in jmeter following is the exception found for one of the post request.

## Script ran successfully from the test url provided by client after changing the url following below exception is found.enter code here

java.util.zip.ZipException: Not in GZIP format

```
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.readHeader(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.hc.LaxGZIPInputStream.<init>(LaxGZIPInputStream.java:43)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$1.create(HTTPHC4Impl.java:198)
at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.initWrapper(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:51)
at org.apache.http.client.entity.LazyDecompressingInputStream.read(LazyDecompressingInputStream.java:63)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1850)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:477)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:598)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253)
at com.blazemeter.jmeter.controller.JMeterThreadParallel.run(JMeterThreadParallel.java:61)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

==========================================================================
Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure to add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager/) and configure it to send [`Accept-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) header with the value of `gzip` (at least)
2. If your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler request body is in plain text you will need to compress it via i.e. [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor)